# How do I exclude folders/files from my Maven War build?

Tags: java, angular, maven

I have a Java 8 backend application that uses an angular 6 front end. During the maven build it takes about 15 minutes to copy in the raw angular 6 source files and node modules. Seeing that I only need the compiled angular 6 /dist folder I would like to ignore/exclude the angular source.

I am using the maven-war-plugin (v. 3.2.2) to package my war. I have tried using both packagingExcludes and warSourceExcludes but in the end the total build still takes 20 minutes and includes my angular source files and all the node modules (an extra total 300 MBs).

My file structure is as such.

```
Java_WAR_App
    src
        main
            java
            resources
            webapp
                dist (compiled angular)
                angular_app (folder to exclude)
                WEB-INF
```

Here is my current maven-war-plugin

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- DON'T include the raw angular folder or build takes forever -->
                <packagingExcludes>src/main/webapp/angular_app/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

For the life of me I don't know why this is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After trying many different ways to exclude the folder, all failing, I simply moved the raw angular code out of the webapp and placed it at the same level as the java folder.